# Jquery chian within chian

Tags: jquery, chaining

I have a piece of code which I have chained like this:

```
$('iframe').contents().find('item').text();
```

I would like to add something inside the chain like this:

```
$('iframe').contents().find(   $('item').next().text()   );
```

This doesn't work for me but Im pretty sure I once saw it done like this, but I can't remember the correct way. So help on this is appreciated. Please note the regular way (chaining everything) doesn't work in my script that's why I have to result to this method.

**EDIT** 
This is the code Im working:

```
    var $me = $('#iframe').contents().find('body *:eq(285)'),
        crazyNumber = 99999999,
        allOfYou = [
            { 
                elements: $me.parentsUntil('.list'),
                target: $me.parentsUntil('.list').parent()
            },
            { 
                elements: $me.nextUntil('.list'),
                target: $me.nextUntil('.list').andSelf().filter(':last').next()
            },
            { 
                elements: $me.prevUntil('.list'),
                target: $me.prevUntil('.list').andSelf().filter(':last').prev()
            }
        ],
        sorted = allOfYou.sort(function (objA, objB) {
            var a = objA.elements.length + 1 || crazyNumber,
                b = objB.elements.length + 1 || crazyNumber;
            return a - b;
        });



  alert(sorted[0].target.text());
```

This will not work because `.list` is also in iframe. So for instance

```
$me.parentsUntil('.list')
```

Should actually be

```
$me.parentsUntil('#iframe').contents().find('.list')
```

This will not work because there are multiple `.list` Jquery will find a different .list every other time. So I need it to say something like:

```
$('#iframe').contents().find( $('body *:eq(285)').parentsUntil('.list') )
```

I have to put everything in the find selector

Comment: What are you *really* trying to do? What significance does the text have?

Comment: @Blender There is nothing special to the text itself, its just an example code for something bigger Im working on. The regular way doesnt work in my script (long story..)

Comment: It's a result of my previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16250592/referring-twice-to-elements-in-iframe

Comment: Post your HTML and explain what you're trying to do. Without details, this question is unanswerable.

Comment: @Blender So you are saying this kind of chaining is by definition imposible: `$( $(code) );` and that I should result to some other approach to the problem..?

Comment: Well, I honestly have no idea what your problem even is, so I can't tell you for sure.

Comment: @Blender I have edited the question, hope its clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.each()`:

```
$('iframe').contents().find('item').each(function() {
    $(this).parentsUntil('.list')...
});
```

Comment: The code still doesn't work. The problem is that the document structure changes, so someone was nice to write me the code above to acount for these changes. However now I sometimes get the .list but sometimes I get img or something else(on refresh) which shouldn't be the case if you look at the code. But at least now Im getting response, which was not the case earlier so the each method works fine, its the code( I think the math) that needs to be changed. Thank you very much:)

Comment: On seconds thoughts....How is this different than the code above, Im already declaring element at index:285 How does each method change this..? I found out Im just getting output for the indexed element, so essentially the whole code doesn't do anything. It just looks for index:whatever and output that.

Comment: If you can think of anything else please let me know (been at this for days now..)

Comment: @Youss: I can't tell what you're asking here. You really should explain your problem clearly and post your HTML.

Comment: Im scraping a news website over here http:www.nu.nl/ So that is the HTML:) I echo (using php) the content in iframe and trying to get the class `.list` for which there are multiple throughout the page. Im trying to get the closest `.li` relative to element with index:anything. Basically this code over here http://jsfiddle.net/terryyounghk/FzA78/ The only difference is that Im targeting Iframe content.

Comment: @Youss: So for that specific example, what is the sorting function for?

Comment: It sorts out all the elements with the same class, leaving only the one closest to the "starting point" which is $me